# how to automate the installation of simple apps on linux or unix

Tags: linux, unix, automation, installation

In my testing I will be installing and uninstalling a simple programs/apps through command line. I want to automate this process. It asks simple inputs during the installation like yes, no and paths.

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`./configure && make && make install` is not simple for you?

Comment: here my application is a bin file, when i do ./fine-name.bin it will ask for inputs yes | no | paths. Is it can be achieved through ./configure && make && make install..?

Comment: so you need input directly ./myprogram.bin + 2 arguments, right? and you want that seems like ./autoinstall myprogram?

Comment: Yes, it will be like when ./myprogram.bin starts installation in the middle it will ask for inputs as i said yes | no | directory paths, etc. every time it is same, so i thought of automating this process which will save 20 X 5 mins per day for me.  Thanks